# Sequential execution for thread pool

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

Working on a POC, where I'm using a ThreadPoolTaskExecutor for parrallel processing, although it's a working solution, but I'm trying to make my thread pool to execute in a sequential order,
PoolSize: 10
MaxPool: 20
Queue: 1000
Main thread which keeps fetching record in batch of 4 all the time, and the worker thread when task submitted
Stage 1 :Fetch data from db in a sequence then

Stage 2: submitted task
Stage 2.1: I have implemented a callable interface where I'm doing 2 thing

1. read/write operation - Ist
2. proccessing operation - IInd
   but the problem is sometime 1st process takes sometime due to which some other worker thread comes and process the operation
   Which results in breaking the order.
   Order: 1-> 3-> 2-> 4
   Expected: 1-> 2-> 3-> 4

Is there a better way to approach this problem, if yes then please do share with an example

I have tried few solution given,

1. Thread priority
2. Latch
3. basic synchronization

Making single thread design is not an option
Expecting: 1->2->3->4
Getting: 2->1->4->3

Comment: I may have misunderstood your question, but all the interest of having more than one thread to execute some tasks is because the tasks are not correlated. If for you it is important that task 1 ends before tasks 2 starts and so on, you simply shouldn't be using parallelization but a single thread solution. Nothing stops you though from batching the 4 tasks into a single thread and parallelizing the other batches.

Comment: If you have multiple threads there is no way you can enforce the ordering, even if you have 1 thread reading from the queue and dispatching to 4 threads you don't know which one will execute first. You don't control which thread is currently active etc. If the ordering is important don't use multiple threads.

Comment: Yes, I agree. What is was looking if there’s a way to enforce a task, it would be much help…. Will change the design